# MySQL - Get the year when there are most registered

Tags: mysql, select, numbers, max

I have this table (named EMP) in MySQL:

```
EMPNO ENAME   JOB       MGR  HIREDATE     SAL      COMM DEPTNO
----- -----  -------   ----  -------- --------  ------- ------
7369 SMITH  CLERK     7902 13-JUN-83   800.00              20
7499 ALLEN  SALESMAN  7698 15-AUG-83 1,600.00   300.00     30
7521 WARD   SALESMAN  7698 26-MAR-84 1,250.00   500.00     30
7566 JONES  MANAGER   7839 31-OCT-83 2,975.00              20
7654 MARTIN SALESMAN  7698 05-DEC-83 1,250.00 1,400.00     30
7698 BLAKE  MANAGER   7839 11-JUL-84 2,850.00              30
7782 CLARK  MANAGER   7839 14-MAY-84 2,450.00              10
7788 SCOTT  ANALYST   7566 05-MAR-84 3,000.00              20
7839 KING   PRESIDENT      09-JUL-84 5,000.00              10
7844 TURNER SALESMAN  7698 04-JUN-84 1,500.00  .00         30
7876 ADAMS  CLERK     7788 04-JUN-84 1,100.00              20
7900 JAMES  CLERK     7698 23-JUL-84   950.00              30
7902 FORD   ANALYST   7566 05-DEC-83 3,000.00              20
7934 MILLER CLERK     7782 21-NOV-83 1,300.00              10
```

How can I write a Select query that returns the year (HIREDATE column) when there are most number of employees (rows) registered?

Comment: Is this really MySQL? And if so, is that a real DATE column type or a CHAR column holding dd-MON-yy strings? It looks like an Oracle date output format to me... MySQL uses YYYY-MM-DD.

Answer (score 1):

What about

```
SELECT YEAR(hiredate) FROM emp 
  GROUP BY YEAR(hiredate) 
  ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC
  LIMIT 1
```

?

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
SELECT COUNT(1), YEAR(HIREDATE) FROM EMP GROUP BY YEAR(HIREDATE);
```

Comment: he wants to return year value with max count

Comment: Thanks, didn't notice that. He should add order by, just as in Wisdom's answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select year(hiredate), count(*) from emp 
group by year(hiredate) order by 2 desc limit 1
```

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
SELECT count(*) as total FROM emp GROUP BY hiredate ORDER BY total DESC LIMIT 1;
```